# Приходят пустые данные о платеже

Tags: android, google-play

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {        
    if (requestCode == 228) { // часть отвечающая за приём данных о платеже
        try {
            Bundle response = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), lastSku, "inapp", security); //lastSku - имя (id) продаваемого элемента
            { //эту часть добавил в фигурные скобки, т.к. она мне не нужна (оставил лишь чтоб посмотреть что она даёт)
                Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
                int responseCode = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE"); //==0
                if (responseCode == 0) {
                    ArrayList<String> ownedSkus =
                            ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST"); // в нём 0 элементов
                    ArrayList<String>  purchaseDataList =
                            ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST"); // тоже 0
                    ArrayList<String>  signatureList =
                            ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE"); // тоже 0
                    String continuationToken =
                            ownedItems.getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN"); //==null

                    for (int i = 0; i < purchaseDataList.size(); ++i) { //не срабатывает из-за нуля
                        String purchaseData = purchaseDataList.get(i);
                        String signature = signatureList.get(i);
                        String sku = ownedSkus.get(i);

                        // do something with this purchase information
                        // e.g. display the updated list of products owned by user
                    }

                    // if continuationToken != null, call getPurchases again
                    // and pass in the token to retrieve more items
                }
            }
            int code = response.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");//==0
            if (code == 0) {
                String signature = response.getString("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE"); //==null
                String s = response.getString("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA"); //==null
                JSONObject purchaseData = new JSONObject(s); //здесь он вылетает с NullPointerException
                purchaseData.getString("orderId");
                purchaseData.getString("packageName");
                purchaseData.getString("productId");
                purchaseData.getString("purchaseTime");
                purchaseData.getString("purchaseState");
                purchaseData.getString("developerPayload");
                purchaseData.getString("purchaseToken");

            } else if (code != 1) { //сюда он не попадал
                Toast.makeText(this,"IAP ERROR " + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (RemoteException e) { //сюда он не попадал
            Toast.makeText(this,"Connection error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (JSONException e) { //сюда он не попадал
            Toast.makeText(this,"Response parse error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    simpleFacebook.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data); //у меня ещё авторизация в фейсбук в этом окошке подключена
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Запускал на телефоне, где главный гуглоаккаунт - аккаунт продавца. В developer console в настройки -> сведения об аккаунте -> аккаунты тестировщиков тоже его прописал и поставил отдавать LICENSED.
Пишет "Издатель не может купить этот товар".

P.S. Кстати, в тех случаях, когда выпадает "проверьте подключение к интернету", он тоже отдаёт нули и null-ы. Так должно быть?

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Comment: Увы я потерял исходник(